# Mysql filter duplicate records on select query within time

Tags: mysql, sql

```
| Id| tollgateName              | deviceTime    | latlng                  | dateTime            |
+-----------+---------------------------+---------------+-------------------------+---------------------+
| 8768 | Pallikonda Toll Plaza     | 1633119455000 | 12.90588222,78.95292444 | 2021-10-02 01:47:35 |
| 8768 | Pallikonda Toll Plaza     | 1633119465000 | 12.90588222,78.95292444 | 2021-10-02 01:47:45 |
| 8768 | Vaniyambadi Toll Plaza    | 1633122527000 | 12.64822667,78.58320889 | 2021-10-02 02:38:47 |
| 8768 | Vaniyambadi Toll Plaza    | 1633122537000 | 12.64822667,78.58320889 | 2021-10-02 02:38:57 |
| 8768 | Palayam Toll Plaza        | 1633131743000 | 12.00751444,78.08155556 | 2021-10-02 05:12:23 |
| 8768 | Palayam Toll Plaza        | 1633131753000 | 12.00751444,78.08155556 | 2021-10-02 05:12:33 |
| 8768 | Pallikonda Toll Plaza     | 1633293799000 | 12.90589444,78.95211556 | 2021-10-04 02:13:19 |
| 8768 | Pallikonda Toll Plaza     | 1633293809000 | 12.90589444,78.95211556 | 2021-10-04 02:13:29 |
| 8768 | Chennasamudram Toll Plaza | 1633296398000 | 12.91050667,79.40219556 | 2021-10-04 02:56:38 |
| 8768 | Sriperumbudur Toll Plaza  | 1633300708000 | 12.98126889,79.96741333 | 2021-10-04 04:08:28 |
| 8768 | Sriperumbudur Toll Plaza  | 1633300718000 | 12.98126889,79.96741333 | 2021-10-04 04:08:38 | 8765 | Vaniyambadi Toll Plaza    | 1633122527000 | 12.64822667,78.58320889 | 2021-10-02 02:38:47 |
| 8765 | Vaniyambadi Toll Plaza    | 1633122537000 | 12.64822667,78.58320889 | 2021-10-02 02:38:57 |
| 8765 | Palayam Toll Plaza        | 1633131743000 | 12.00751444,78.08155556 | 2021-10-02 05:12:23 |
| 8765 | Palayam Toll Plaza        | 1633131753000 | 12.00751444,78.08155556 | 2021-10-02 05:12:33 |
| 8765 | Pallikonda Toll Plaza     | 1633293799000 | 12.90589444,78.95211556 | 2021-10-04 02:13:19 |
| 8765 | Pallikonda Toll Plaza     | 1633293809000 | 12.90589444,78.95211556 | 2021-10-04 02:13:29 |
| 8765 | Chennasamudram Toll Plaza | 1633296398000 | 12.91050667,79.40219556 | 2021-10-04 02:56:38 |
```

Hi guys my requirement is I want to filter this mysql records based on time and tollgate.

1. If the tollgateName is duplicates within 30mins then those duplicated records need to be filtered from the selected query or else that record is okay to be in the list
2. there are multiple Ids in the table so I want to use the Id IN clause
3. The where clause should be like Id IN ("","") and deviceTime between ? and ? like this.

Comment: *If the tollgateName is duplicates within 30mins then those duplicated records need to be filtered from the selected query or else that record is okay to be in the list* If there are 3 rows as T+0, T+20 and T+40 then the output must contain only 1st row (2nd and 3rd are filtered due to the gap between this and previous row is less than 30) or 1st and 3rd rows?

Comment: Please post query you've tried and illustrate the expected result.